# actionscript 3.0 creating sprite instances in a for loop

Tags: actionscript-3

The for loop in the following code works (puts two instances of a movie clip on the stage), but how come it works? Isn't it creating more than one instance with the same name? If I pull the code out of the loop as shown in the part commented out, then I get the 1151 error message I would have expected about a namespace conflict.

```
for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {
    var mascot:Mascot = new Mascot();
    mascot.x = 150*j + 100;
    mascot.y = 100;
    addChild(mascot);
}
/*
var mascot:Mascot = new Mascot();
mascot.x = 100;
mascot.y = 300;
addChild(mascot);

var mascot:Mascot = new Mascot();
mascot.x = 250;
mascot.y = 300;
addChild(mascot);
*/
```

Comment: Just a guess: for loops have their own scope.

Comment: Yes, I considered that. But I ran some tests that disproved that theory.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting when you are not  using a loop doesn't have anything to do with instance names.

Without the loop you are trying to create 2 variables with the same name and that is a compile error.

Change it to the following and it will work.

```
var mascot:Mascot = new Mascot();
mascot.x = 100;
mascot.y = 300;
addChild(mascot);

mascot = new Mascot();
mascot.x = 250;
mascot.y = 300;
addChild(mascot);
```

Both sprites get assigned a unique instance name so both code samples work fine.

Comment: Yes, I know the error is because of trying to create 2 variables with the same name - but isn't that exactly what the "for" loop is doing? I understand the code that doesn't work; what I don't understand is how come the "for" loop DOES work.

Comment: Not really, as far as the the compiler is concerned there is only 1 variable name even if the for loop iterates n times, you do create n `Mascot` instances but only 1 variable is used to reference them.